# Image loader does not show on html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using ajax jquery to load an image loader .gif file while request for data is sent. i am using beforeSend to add the image to the div with an id. when results are found then image disapears. i used chrome inspection to see if image will show and it does. the web page does not show the gif

**ajax jquery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#whois").submit(function(){
    var site = $("#site").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "whohelper.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: { ip: site },
      async: false,
      dataType: "html",
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#rs").html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif"/>');
      },
      success: function(result) {
        $("#rs").html(result);
      },
      error: function() {
        $("#rs").html('<strong>ERROR:</strong> Please try again later');
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: You know the purpose of `async: false,`? Because that's why... That's why UI has no time to be repainted and so cannot show the image. Remove it!

Comment: Or let it be, if you need this, and just set the loading gif before the `$.ajax`. You don't need to use `beforeSend`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Preload the image by placing it in the DOM while hiding it. This will ensure that when the AJAX gets called, the image will be loaded.

```
<img id="loader" src="ajax-loader.gif" style="display: none;">
```

Then in your JS, just show/hide the loading image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#whois").submit(function(e) {
        // better to use e.preventDefault(); than return false;
        e.preventDefault();

        // always a good idea to cache elements that you will re-using
        var $rs = $('#rs'),
            $loader = $('#loader');

        var site = $("#site").val();

        // show loading image
        $loader.css('display', '');

        $.ajax({
            url: "whohelper.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { ip: site },
            async: false, // bad idea
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (result) {
                $rs.html(result);
            },
            error: function () {
                $rs.html('<strong>ERROR:</strong> Please try again later');
            },
            complete: function () {
                // hide loading image
                $loader.css('display', 'none'); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If there is still no image, then you probably have an incorrect path to your image.